# Execution failed for task : 'app.transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. after importing project to android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android

I was unable to run the application in android studio 3.0.1(stable one). Earlier it was good in android version 2.3.2, but facing this issue in this version of android studio.

As i have commented the retrolambda plugin's in gradle files but still facing this issue. I have tried to fix the issue by searching related questions in stack overflow, but doesn't worked for me, so raising the question.

Please find the attached blocks of code with error message for reference and please comment if you need any additional information required related this issue:

Thanks in advance.

**build.gradle (project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app):**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
//29 , 3.2.1
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 61
        versionName "4.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField("boolean", "testing", "false")
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue("string", "truecallerKey", "XXXXXX")
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField("boolean", "testing", "true")
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix ".testing"
            resValue("string", "truecallerKey", "XXXXXX")
        }
        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix ".beta"
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile(name: "truesdk-0.5", ext: "aar")
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error Message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/12.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/6.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/71.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/72.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/62.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/63.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/20.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/40.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/46.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/42.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/16.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/66.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/67.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/77.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/78.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/21.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/50.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/74.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/75.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/52.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/39.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/57.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/58.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/1.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/17.jar --input /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --output /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/52.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/54.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/55.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/56.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/57.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/58.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/59.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/60.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/61.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/62.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/63.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/64.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/65.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/66.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/67.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/68.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/69.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/70.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/71.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/72.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/73.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/74.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/75.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/76.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/77.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/78.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/79.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/80.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/81.jar --classpath_entry /Users/cepl/Desktop/rapidoPax/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/82.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/cepl/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/cepl/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No Maddy, still didn't get any solution.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Have you got the solution ? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same problem in Ionic3.So just run these commands..

1. **cordova clean android**
2. **ionic cordova build android**

After performing 2 command you will get your .apk file

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and update all possible libs.

Comment: Hi Filipe, i cleaned my project and updated all my libs, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just had the same problem, and cleaning (`./gradlew clean`) was the key. After that, I can build fine.

Comment: does not work, neither has any supporting arguments as to why should it work

Answer (score 1):

I also got same problem, Issue were resolved using following line.

Open gradle.properties and add "android.enableD8.desugaring = true"