# Didn't find class "org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener" in typesense Client Configuration

Tags: android, kotlin, typesense

I added typesense jar libraries in to the my anroid project and getting crash when calling the client configuration.

**Stacktrace**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.soho.mytypesense, PID: 30422
                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.find(ServiceFinder.java:265)
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.<init>(ClientConfig.java:143)
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.<init>(ClientConfig.java:509)
                    at org.typesense.api.ApiCall.<init>(ApiCall.java:53)
                    at org.typesense.api.Client.<init>(Client.java:27)
                    at com.soho.mytypesense.MainActivity.callTypeSense(MainActivity.kt:55)
                    at com.soho.mytypesense.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soho.mytypesense-6-OlfKw7m2tnLlbdQMGUMQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.soho.mytypesense-6-OlfKw7m2tnLlbdQMGUMQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.find(ServiceFinder.java:265) 
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.<init>(ClientConfig.java:143) 
                    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.<init>(ClientConfig.java:509) 
                    at org.typesense.api.ApiCall.<init>(ApiCall.java:53) 
                    at org.typesense.api.Client.<init>(Client.java:27) 
                    at com.soho.mytypesense.MainActivity.callTypeSense(MainActivity.kt:55) 
                    at com.soho.mytypesense.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43) 
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.soho.mytypesense'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soho.mytypesense"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

    implementation files('libs/typesense-java-0.0.3.jar')

    /*implementation ('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1'){
        exclude module : 'javax.inject'
    }*/

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And I've tried [Jersey dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48625977/1891038). But after that i got another compile issue as like this **Duplicate class found**

```
Duplicate class javassist.ByteArrayClassPath found in modules javassist-3.20.0-GA (org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA) and typesense-java-0.0.3 (typesense-java-0.0.3.jar)
Duplicate class javassist.CannotCompileException found in modules javassist-3.20.0-GA (org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA) and typesense-java-0.0.3 (typesense-java-0.0.3.jar)
Duplicate class javassist.ClassClassPath found in modules javassist-3.20.0-GA (org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA) and typesense-java-0.0.3 (typesense-java-0.0.3.jar) many more...
```

**Typesense Function**

```
private fun callClient(){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        try {
            val nodes: ArrayList<Node> = ArrayList()
            nodes.add(Node("https", "ts-cluster-staging....", "443"))

            val configuration = Configuration(
                nodes, Duration.ofSeconds(2), "FXOHZ..."
            )

            val client = Client(configuration)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

So how to fix this issue and dependency resolution errors?